# how to send email using cakephp email component?

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I try to send a mail using cakephp email component. But mail is not delivering, nor it shows any error message. do i need to set any additional parameters? here is my code snippet:

```
            $this->Email->from='<xyz@yahoo.com>';
    $this->Email->to='<abc@gmail.com>';
    $this->Email->sendAs='both';
    $this->Email->delivery = 'debug';
    $this->Email->send();
```

Comment: I had some problems with the cakephp e-mail component - I found that I could only send mail when using SMTP. You might want to try it to see if it works (http://book.cakephp.org/view/1290/Sending-A-Message-Using-SMTP). Also, do you have your e-mail templates set up? (http://book.cakephp.org/view/1286/Sending-a-basic-message#Setting-up-the-Layouts-1287)

Answer (score 5):

You should try change

```
$this->Email->delivery = 'debug';
```

To

```
$this->Email->delivery = 'mail';
```

Read more at: 
http://api.cakephp.org/class/email-component

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply... This can run on localhost ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$this->Email->from='<xyz@yahoo.com>';
$this->Email->to='<abc@gmail.com>';
```

to

```
$this->Email->from='xyz@yahoo.com';
$this->Email->to='abc@gmail.com';
```

Just now I've solved my problem with it. Cake would not send messages when delivery was set to `mail`, but with google SMTP it worked fine. Google SMTP needed the addresses to be like `Name <email@example.com>`. When I removed the `Name`, `<` and `>` it started to send emails propperly with delivery method set to `mail`.

And by the way it's highly possible it will not run at localhost (because of you being possible spammer or whatever) so try to upload your app to a server and then send the mails.

edit: also change the delivery method to mail. But if you want to see the debug of the mail, you need to do `echo $this->Session->flash('email');` in your view when the debug delivery method is set

Answer (score 0):

Try and replace this:

```
$this->Email->from='<xyz@yahoo.com>';
$this->Email->to='<abc@gmail.com>';
```

With this:

```
$this->Email->from='XYZ <xyz@yahoo.com>';
$this->Email->to='ABC <abc@gmail.com>';
```

I had a similar problem and it seems if you do not specify the name (XYZ, ABC) the email will not be sent and no errors will show. I was using gmail's SMTP server though, hope this helps.

Also here's the Cookbook article on emails: http://book.cakephp.org/view/269/Sending-a-basic-message